# How to add a background color to a styled component based on condition using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

how can i add background color to styled component based on the condition using react and typescript?

what i am trying to do?

I have a MainComponent which renders ListContent within DragAndDropComponent.

Now when user drags a file into DragAndDrop div i want its background color change to grey.

Below is my code,

```
function MainComponent () {
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <SomeOtheComponent/>
        <DragAndDrop>
            <ListContent> //this is the children for the DragAndDrop component and want this to 
                //render within DragAndDrop component
                {condition_true && (
                    <FirstList/>
                )}
                {condition_true && (
                    <SecondList/>
                )}
            </ListContent>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}


const DragAndDrop: React.FC = ({ children }) => { //here i am passing children
    const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
    const [dragCounter, setDragCounter] = useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // componentDidMount()
        setDragCounter(0);
    }, []);

    const handleDrag = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

    const handleDragIn = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev + 1);
        if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
            setDragging(true);
        }
    };

    const handleDragOut = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev - 1);
        if (dragCounter === 0) {
            setDragging(false);
        }
    }; 

    const handleDrop = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragging(false);
        if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
            e.dataTransfer.clearData();
            setDragCounter(0);
        }
    };

    return (
        <DropZone //i want to change background color to this div if dragging true.
            ref={dropRef}
            onDragEnter={handleDragIn}
            onDragLeave={handleDragOut}
            onDragOver={handleDrag}
            onDrop={handleDrop}
        >  
            {children}
        </DropZone>
    );
};


const DropZone = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    //backgroun-color: how to change background color to grey if dragging state true.
`;
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function that is passed the `props` object. Here I've destructured `dragging` and if truthy return the `background: grey` rule, otherwise it returns no rule.

[passed props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

```
const DropZone = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  ${({ dragging }) => dragging && 'background-color:  grey;'}
`;
```

*EDIT: Add `dragging` prop type (`<{ dragging?: boolean }>`) for typescript*

```
const DropZone = styled.div<{ dragging?: boolean }>`
  height: 100%;
  ${({ dragging }) => dragging && 'background-color:  grey;'}
`;
```

Usage

```
<DropZone
  ref={dropRef}
  dragging={dragging} // <-- pass dragging as prop here
  onDragEnter={handleDragIn}
  onDragLeave={handleDragOut}
  onDragOver={handleDrag}
  onDrop={handleDrop}
>  
  {children}
</DropZone>
```

Comment: thanks dropzone is a styled component div and passing dragging ={dragging} to it says property dragging doesnt exist on type intrinsicAttributes. also it seems like there is some typo in the way dragging is used in const DropZone. missing closing curly brackets

Comment: @someuser2491 Yeah, that'd be a typescript issue. Thanks for the heads up about typo, what I get for coding in a text editor; fixed now. I'm not very familiar with typescript, but my guess is you need to do the equivalent of adding `dragging` to the defined propTypes. Does anything in the styled-components typescript [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) help? Perhaps specifically [this](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)?

Comment: Ah okay. i fixed it like this const DropZone = styled.div<{ dragging?: boolean }>` and it works now. thanks.

Comment: @someuser2491 Awesome, great!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this statement up `const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);` to make it accessible outside

```
const DropZone = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    background: ${ dragging ? "grey": ""}
`;
```

Comment: thanks. i tried this and says cannot find name dragging.

Comment: Idk what's the name of the state variable put  your variable name there

Comment: Try moving this statement up const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false); to make it accessible outside